# post's category (forum) in xf_post (xenforo)

Tags: xenforo

I want to display all posts from all threads from one category (forum) but:

[xf_post http://screenshu.com/static/uploads/temporary/c8/xy/5d/zia0a4.jpg](http://screenshu.com/static/uploads/temporary/c8/xy/5d/zia0a4.jpg)

as you can see, there is no cell for category (forum). I just want to know If I can get it from other table?

Answer (score 0):

On Database:
xf_node: all nodes (category , forum , page , ect) with : node_id , parent_node , ...
xf_thread: all threads with: thread_id , node_id

post_id (xf_post) --> thread_id (xf_post , xf_thread) --> node_id (xf_thread , xf_node).

or

node_id(xf_thread , xf_node) --> thread_id (xf_post , xf_thread) --> post_id (xf_post)